# Find page for a specific item in paginate() SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, pagination, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am usign Flask-SQLAlchemy’s `paginate()`. Now I need to find what is the page for a specific comment id.

For example, this will work, if I have all comments in the same page:

```
new_dict['url'] = '/comments#comment_' + str(comment.id)
```

However in my case I need this structure:

```
/comments?page=1#comment_73
```

How can I find what is the page?

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/api.html#flask.ext.sqlalchemy.Pagination), the `Pagination` class has `.items` and `.has_next` properties and a `.next` method we can use:

```
page_number = 0
search = Comment.query.get(15)
query = Comment.query.filter(Comment.id<40)
for num in range(1, query.paginate(1).pages + 1):
    if search in query.paginate(num).items:
        page_number = num
        break
```

or

```
page_number = 0
search = Comment.query.get(15)
pag = Comment.query.filter(Comment.id<40).paginate(1)
while pag.has_next:
    if search in pag.items:
        page_number = num
        break
    pag.next()
```

Comment: What do you think about this way: http://codepad.org/rIasrULq I think that will work

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Celeo's answer won't work. For example, what `pag.next()` does in his code, based on documentations is:

> Returns a Pagination object for the next page.

So, basically, it's doing nothing unless you update your variable; and I recommend you to not create a new query since you already have the comment_id so:

```
comment_id=request.args.get('comment_id')
if comment_id and comment_id.isdigit():
            comment_id = int(comment_id )
            page_number = -1
            index = 1 # page numbers are 1 indexed in Pagination Object
            while comments_pagination_object.has_next:
                for comment in comments_pagination_object.items:
                    if comment.id == comment_id :
                        page_number = index
                        break
                if page_number != -1:
                    break
                index += 1
                product_items = product_items.next()
```

Then, in the URL, you will have something like:

```
/comments?comment_id=2
```

and the part `product_items.next()` is changing the PaginationObject's page till one of it's items (which in this case is a type of `class Comment`) has the same id as your request args.